# How to test this.router.navigateToRoute() in a component

Tags: aurelia

How can i test this.router.navigateToRoute("home") ?

on running test i keep getting.
**Error: A route with name 'home' could not be found. Check that `name: 'home'` was specified in the route's config.**

my test file

```
import { StageComponent } from "aurelia-testing";
import { bootstrap } from "aurelia-bootstrapper";
import { PLATFORM } from "aurelia-pal";
import { Container } from "aurelia-dependency-injection";
import { UserService } from "../../src/shared/services/user-service";
import { RouterConfiguration, Router } from "aurelia-router";

describe("MyComponent with sign up", () => {
  let component;

  beforeEach(() => {
    component = new Container();
    component.get(UserService);
    component.get(Router);
    component.get(RouterConfiguration);
    component = StageComponent.withResources(
      PLATFORM.moduleName("components/auth/auth-component")
    )
      .inView(
        '<auth-component type.bind="type" email.bind="email" password.bind="password"></auth-component>'
      )
      .boundTo({ type: "login", email: "t@1.com", password: "qqqq" });
  });

  it("should render Login", done => {
    component
      .create(bootstrap)
      .then(() => {
        const routeConfig = { name: "login" };
        component.viewModel.activate("", routeConfig);
        component.viewModel.determineActivationStrategy();
        const nameElement = document.querySelector(".LogTest");
        component.viewModel.submit();
        expect(nameElement.innerHTML).toBe("Sign in");
        done();
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e.toString());
      });
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    component.dispose();
  });
});
```

Comment: You can add a spy on the router like this `spyOn(component.viewModel.router, 'navigateToRoute')`. After submit you can assert if the `navigateToRoute` method has been called. On a side note, you are using the same variable name `component` for both the container and the test component. That's confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Your error means you have not registered a route named home in your app.ts, so you would need to do that first and then this would work. However if you are just wanting to navigate to a route like so: https-://[mydomain]/home, then you would need to just use router.navigate and not navigateToRoute. The navigateToRoute function is for routes registered with the router via the initial config set up.

For configuring your router: 
[Router Config](https://aurelia.io/docs/routing/configuration#basic-configuration)

Navigate to route details:
[navigateToRoute](https://aurelia.io/docs/api/router/class/Router/method/navigateToRoute)